# How to check if a Linked List is full using Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am doing an assignment for school and I'm not sure how to check if my linked list is full

I have

```
public boolean isFull()
{
    return back == null;
}
```

But I'm initializing both for null at the beginning so if the list is empty, this method would return true too.

I was thinking maybe

```
public boolean isFull()
{
     if(!isEmpty())
     {
        return back == null:
     }
}
```

What do you think??

**The linked list should not have more than 7 items** I forgot to mention that.

Comment: How does one define "full" for a linked list?

Comment: how "large" is your linked list?

Comment: What does your implementation look like?

Comment: @Matt, there is no underlying array for a linked list (unless it is some very special implementation - but using an array for modeling linked lists would be *very* awkward at any rate).

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a linked list size 7, I forgot to mention that

Comment: @Péter: dangit, you're right. I was thinking of array lists.

Comment: @fgualda87, please add this as an update to your original post, to help people notice it. Btw you need to iterate over the list to detect whether it has more than 7 elements.

Comment: @Matt yes, I'm sorry, I just did

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no such concept as a "full" linked list, unless you've got a specific implementation which has an upper bound for size. Generally linked lists can grow as long as you want them to.

EDIT: Okay, now you've actually explained the aim - I would personally keep a count with the linked list. Many implementations use this so that you can access the size in O(1) complexity. Normally to find the size of a "vanilla" linked list you start at the head of the list and iterate over it, incrementing a count until you reach the tail. That's an O(n) operation. Not too bad for 7 elements, but a pain for a million. Keeping a separate count is easy and cheap.

Comment: My LinkedList shouldn't have more than 7 items. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: So add 1 to counter each time an element gets inserted to the list and remove 1 each time an element gets removed and if counter == 7 then return true?

Answer (score 2):

Since you stated you want to know if the list has 7 elements:

```
public boolean isFull()
{
    return list != null && list.size() >= 7;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that need a parameter list?

Comment: @fgualda87 from code examples the question it looks like he is putting these methods in a class that has a list field

Comment: What do you mean? Don't I need the name of the LinkedList? I have one class to declare the methods and create the LinkedList and the other class to fill it in and play with it.

Comment: @fgualda87 so change the method signature to `public boolean isFull(LinkedList list)`